# Solving a system of ODEs with a zero eigenvalue and non-zero initial velocity

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, initial-value-problems

Consider a system of two second-order linear ODEs for which I have found a solution:

$$
\pmatrix{y_1 \\ y_2} = (A_1\cos\omega t + B_1\sin\omega t )\pmatrix{a \\ b} + \pmatrix{C_1 \\ C_2}
$$

the constant term being due to an eigenvalue of zero for the matrix $A$ in the equation:

$$
\ddot{\boldsymbol{y}} = -A\cdot \boldsymbol{y}
$$

Say I am now given an initial condition of $\dot{\boldsymbol{y}} = (v, 0)^T$ at $t = 0$. Differentiating my solution, I find:

$$
\dot{\boldsymbol{y}} = \pmatrix{v \\ 0} = B_1\omega\pmatrix{a \\ b}
$$

Clearly there is no constant $B_1$ which satisfies this condition. How is it physically possible that my system cannot have an initial velocity? I'm really struggling to see what I might be doing wrong here, and can provide more context for how I arrived at my original equation if necessary. Sorry if this is confusing.

---

Original ODE:

$$
M\cdot\ddot{\boldsymbol{y}} = -\begin{bmatrix}
k & -k \\
-k & k
\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{y}
$$

where $M = \mathrm{diag}(m_1, m_2)$, two known constants. $k$ is also known.

Comment: Could you show us the original ODE?

Comment: @Cesareo apologies for the wait. I have edited the question.

Comment: The system's determinant of the matrix is zero, giving a degenerated case. No mystery: as a consequence, solutions (trajectories) are straight lines

Comment: Ok, thank you. But why does this mean that I can't set an initial velocity for the system?

Answer (score 1):

As $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & -k \\
 -k & k \\
\end{array}
\right) = T^{-1}\Lambda T$ with $T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $\Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 k & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ we have

$$
m\ddot y + T^{-1}\Lambda Ty=0\ \ \Rightarrow mT\ddot y + \Lambda T y = 0
$$

so calling $z = T y$ we have the decoupled linear system

$$
m\ddot z + \Lambda z = 0
$$

with solution

$$
\cases{
z_1 = c_1\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}}t\right)+ c_2\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}}t\right)\\
z_2 = c_3+c_4 t
}
$$

so we have four independent constants to configure with the initial/boundary conditions. From $z$ to $y$ we proceed as $y = T^{-1}z$. Concluding, we are free to configure those initial/boundary conditions as needed.